# Template class arguments as type

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class

```
template<typename T, typename U>
class A {
  T i;
}
```

And i have a class B that should use the same types as class A

```
template<typename A_Type>
class B
    : public A_Type
{
  T j; // here I need a class member of the same type as the first type of A_Type (T from class A)
}
```

So I would need something like

```
template<typename A_Type<T, U>>
class B
    : public A_Type
{
  T j; 
}
```

This notation is obviously not working but is there a notation that would fit my needs?

Comment: "...should use the same types as class A..." -- There is no class A. There is just a class *template* called A...

Comment: Should only `A<T,U>` instances be accepted as `A_Type`s  in `B<A_Type>` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can provide a member alias in `A` :

```
template<typename T, typename U>
class A {
  T i;
  using value_type = T;
};

template<typename A_Type>
class B
    : public A_Type
{
  typename A_Type::value_type;
};
```

Or use specialization to deduce the type of the argument:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
class A {
  T i;
  using value_type = T;
};

template<typename A_Type>
class B : public A_Type {};

template <typename T,typename U>
class B<A<T,U>> : A<T,U> {
    T j;
};
```

As mentioned in comments, try to be careful with terminology. Using the terms right avoids issues. Neither `A` nor `B` are classes. They are class templates. And the member alias should be `protected` (or placed in a seperate trait `template <typename A> struct get_T_from_instantiation_of_A;`)

Comment: `value_type` should be `protected` at least.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just pass that type ?

```
template<typename A_Type, typename T>
class B
    : public A_Type
{
  T j; // here I need a class member of the same type as the first type of A_Type (T from class A)
}
```

Comment: Yeah this was my solution for now but it is not a very clean one imo. Because you always have to add the type twice (B<A<T, U>, T> instead of B<A<T, U>>)

Comment: @str0yd if it should be possible to instantiate some `B<A<T,U>,V>` with `V!=T`, this is actually the way to go, and for `T==V` an alias can be used `template <typename T,typename U> using BA = B<A<T,U>,T>;`

Comment: @str0yd: is the member j of class B at the right place ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust yea it is in the right place. In my concrete example class A has some position : T and the class B is a "range check" for this position, maxPos : T and minpos : T

Comment: @str0yd: why isn't this in the class A ?

Answer (score 0):

You could create some type traits to help out.

First one to test if a type is really an `A` type:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
struct is_A_type {
    static std::false_type test(...);
    
    template<template<class...> class U, class... V,
                      std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<U<V...>, A<V...>>, int> = 0>
    static std::true_type test(const U<V...>&);

    static constexpr bool value = decltype(test(std::declval<T>()))::value;
};

template<class T>
inline constexpr bool is_A_type_v = is_A_type<T>::value;
```

Then a trait to get the type of the first template parameter:

```cpp
template<class T>
struct first_type {
    static void test(...);

    template<template<class...> class U, class F, class... V>
    static auto test(const U<F, V...>&) -> F;

    using type = decltype(test(std::declval<T>()));
};

template<class T>
using first_type_t = typename first_type<T>::type;
```

These traits could then be used like so:

```cpp
template<class A_Type>
class B : public A_Type {
    static_assert(is_A_type_v<A_Type>, "A_Type must be an A type");

    using T = first_type_t<A_Type>;
    
    T j;
};
```